# Bootstrapping wifi over bluetooth

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-zero

I"m looking for a way to configure the raspberry pi zero in a completely headless way.

I have seen many IoT devices that use a BLE connection to then configure a wifi connection. Can anyone suggest a way to do this using the pi zero?

The flow would work something like this,

- Power up the pi, it is not configured to wifi so enables Bluetooth.
- using a phone, connect via Bluetooth. (probably with a custom app I'm guessing)
- enter in wifi details
- pi connects to wifi
- pi can now begin designed IoT function.

Comment: Bear in mind many phones won't have **BLE** even if they do have Bluetooth capability for an older version. You might find [How can I easily configure Wi-Fi on a smart device without a screen?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/651/how-can-i-easily-configure-wi-fi-on-a-smart-device-without-a-screen) on the IoT site helpful too.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this question.  soething that would work kind of like a sonos device does where the sonos app first recognizes a new sonos device nearby and prompts the user to add it to the local sonos network and then do an OTA update.